# Archivo html para contener la respuesta de consulta query

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, postgresql

Tengo esta función para buscar por nombre los usuarios de una base de datos postgres:

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = $1', [req.query.q]);
    res.json(response.rows);
};
```

En el index html se ingresa el nombre en un input y con el siguiente método me redirige a la siguiente url:

```
  buscar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  window.location.assign('/users?q=' + input.value);
```

Lo que necesito hacer es editar el código html de esta url donde me muestra los datos del usuario para mostrarlos en una tabla en que tome los datos del json. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para linkear un archivo html con esta url siendo que siempre va a ser distinta? (en función del nombre ingresado en el imput). (http://localhost:3000/users?q=santiago)

Comment: Podrias adjuntar un ejemplo de la respuesta que trae la url?

Comment: ahí está. y ahí me muestra un json [{"id":8,"nombre":"santiago","origen":null,"empadronamiento":"total","vacunas":null,"vias_de_excepcion":null}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes modificar la respuesta de la función de nodejs para que no responda el json que mostraste, sino que muestre el html de la tabla

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = $1', [req.query.q]);
    const rows = response.rows

    let html = `
        <table id="tabla">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Origen</th>
                    <th>Empadronamiento</th>
                    <th>vacunas</th>
                    <th>vias_de_excepcion</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                ${rows.map((row) => `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${row.id}</td>
                        <td>${row.nombre}</td>
                        <td>${row.origen}</td>
                        <td>${row.empadronamiento}</td>
                        <td>${row.vacunas}</td>
                        <td>${row.vias_de_excepcion}</td>
                    </tr>
                `).join('')}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    `

    res.send(html);
};
```

Comment: Bien, eso para crear la tabla, pero cómo hago para que el html de la tabla me aparezca en la url del usuario que se ingrese?

Comment: Eso ya no lo comprendo, puedes explicar un poco mejor?

Comment: Tengo el index.html, ahí hay un input text y con el botón me redirige a una url donde me muestra en json los datos del nombre. por ejemplo: del index paso a http://localhost:3000/users?q=santiago donde me muestra el json. La pregunta es cómo editar el html de esa url, no el index.html

Comment: Listo, modifique mi respuesta

Comment: Uh, perfecto. Muchisimas gracias. Una consulta más porfa: Cómo edito esa tabla para que se vea más bonita?

Comment: osea, cómo relacionar ese html con otro archivo css?

Comment: https://codepen.io/lebim01/pen/rNaMJZy